# Time since the code has been running

Tags: r, systemtime

The following code shows total code run time:
Dummy code;

```
require(tictoc)
require(svMisc)
tic()
y<-NA
for(i in 1:1000000){
  progress(i)
  x<-sample(rnorm(1000),1)
  y[i]<- sqrt(x)
}
max(y, na.rm = T)
toc()
```

***I want to see the running time (stopwatch) only on the console without waiting for code run completion***, similar to the code completion percentage display on the console using svMisc package. I can not use any profiling method based on utils or profvis package due to some weird rstudio crashing.

Comment: Look for `Parallel Computing` in r.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
start <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:10) {
    elapsed <- difftime(Sys.time(), start, units = "secs")
    cat(sprintf("\r%1.0f seconds elapsed", elapsed))
    Sys.sleep(1)
}
cat("\n")
```